# HttpHandler is not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to create a custom Handler but my debugger is not hitting the HandlerClass code.

[image]

Here is the class

```
 public class HandlerClass : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return true; 
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: any help from anyone?

Comment: You should make sure your url contains the aspx and the type is as same as the namespace and class.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Because you do not need an entry in the web.config to make the handler work. Just request url `/HandlerClass.ashx`

Comment: @Brando - It is exactly the same....

Comment: @VDWWD- I am just trying to understand how handlers work. Well, that is not how handler will work. It should be called itself rather than me hitting a certain url

Comment: Try this to check if it has returned response. `public class HandlerClass: IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        bool IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;
            response.Write("<html><body><h1>Wow.. We created our first handler");
            response.Write("</h1></body></html>");
        }

        #endregion
    }`

Comment: why did you put IHttpHandler instead of void?

Comment: What's the application pool mode? Your handler can only work in integrated mode.

Comment: My app is not on IIS, so how to find which pool it is using?

Comment: Do you mean you used the VS to debug the handler? As I says you should make sure your request url contains .aspx. If you create a default web form template, it will use friendly url by default. You should make sure your url contains aspx

Comment: Yes, I am debugging from VS. Even when I am hitting aspx page, it is not working